# Consume a soap webservice in spring microservice with spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, rest, soap, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a microservice for payment which I must consume a soap webservice in it. also each request is proxing by a spring cloud gateway which gets an authentication token from microservice and then sends the request to external services. something like this:

microservice --> gateway --> external service

Now I wanna know how to call a soap service from microservice by putting gateway token on the request.

I used apache-cxf and spring-ws dependencies in pom.xml